# ASP.NET MVC Membership Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'm developing ASP.NET in C# after performing aspnet_regsql on my database. I want to track Game objects and map them to users... if possible I'd like a user have a list of Games, but obviously I can't put that in the current Membership implementation unless I write my own which I'm trying to avoid.

```
public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
```

In MVC however, how do I actually map this in another model (which would be using the same database, would just be another table within that database).

```
public class Games
{
    [key]
    public int GameId

    Properties/Details about the game here.... 

    //Foreign key to map to the specific user this Game belongs to
    [Required]
    public int UserId
}
```

Would this actually work?  Does MVC in the background make sure that `UserId` is `aspnet_User.UserId`? I'd hate to create a extension of the `MembershipProvider` interface, but if the above doesn't work I suppose I might have to!

Also, I'm not interested in leveraging profiles; as you can see, the data I'm trying to map to will be central to this application. Trying to parse through profile data is practically impossible when it also needs to map to other objects!

Comment: just to clarify, you are using Entity Framework, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to join the `Game` with `aspnet_User`, then your setup will not work. For that you  would have to map `aspnet_User` as an entity.

On the other hand if you only need to retrieve the Games for a particular user then your model will work. Make sure you manually create a FK to keep the data integrity.

**Edit**

You can map the `aspnet_User` table as an entity as follows

```
[Table("aspnet_User")]
public class User
{
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     // other props
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  So MVC will essentially map 'UserId' to the proper 'aspnet_User' that 'Membership' is using.  The secrete sauce behind MVC scares me at some times :\

Comment: @AndrewHarris I think what you are talking about is the Entity Framework not MVC

Comment: Ah, good point!  Just getting back to development and Msft has a lot of things doing magical things.  I'll need to brush up on EF to achieve the effect.  As it stands, I can't see how EF would know I specifically want I map UserId to that of aspnet_User.UserId.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new game, simply get the current user's id which is a guid (not an INT as above - you want a guid, its a bit more secure and less easily guessable in case this is ever stored on a form and allows a user to inject new values into it)
That part is

```
Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```

To query this would be simply

```
ctx.Games.Where(o=>o.UserId=Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey)
```

If you want the relation there though, consider @Eranga's relationship.If you want to consider cascade deletes (as in you delete the user, all games go bye bye) then see the section at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738695.aspx

Comment: I don't see how a GUID would be more secure? Don't allow user id in the query string or to be posted. Indexing a GUID is a lot more inefficient than using a sequenced int. I tend to only recommend guids if portability is required.

Comment: @jgauffin Int based user ids are sequential and easily predictable. You are relying on a developer to not post this ID somewhere and its inevitable this will happen. Hence the UserIds in the membership provider are guid based. To say 'don't allow' means you rely on a developer remembering not to do this as opposed to implementing a more secure pattern. Also considering MVC provides brainless rendering of a view via Html.EditorFor, you then have to remember to exclude userids from every model or view model you are displaying. Again, a lot of 'remembering' for a developer to do.

Comment: A guid can be easy to find too. Just search for users and hover over the user details link..

Comment: @jgauffin I think you are missing the point though : ) say /UserProfile/284 allows you to view information for YOU. This queries games, etc. Now how difficult is it for that user to enter /UserProfile/1 and view the admin (assuming they are the first user?). Your system may not work like this but _many_ vulnerabilities of this type exist and this is a simple case. Having an easily guessable user id opens yourself up to a host of attacks where a user can try to post info as a different user, or use CSRF to proxy a request through an auth'd user to assign admin privs for another user, etc.

Comment: These attacks are well known and fall under the 'information tampering' category. The case you provided above doesn't deal with a user being able to tamper with _any_ data that happens to make it to the user's browser that happens to rely on this field. I wouldn't ever give end users (besides admin) the ability to see other user ids. I would contain a mapping simply for that function to specifically prevent this by for ex. showing them the user's unique login id instead. My point is, your approach would hope a developer wouldn't ever use that field _anywhere_

Comment: that reaches the client, and thats not a consistent and secure pattern. I have a couple examples in a pluralsight.com video series under CSRF and information tampering if you have a subscription to them. The videos I think are going live today or tomorrow.

Comment: You are missing the point. Most sites have a user search feature. Click on any user to come to its profile. You get `/UserProfile/Details/XXXX` where X is for the user you clicked on. It doesn't matter if XXXX is a guid or an integer.

Comment: Using a guid is just making things barely harder. Input validation is the only way to make sure that the users edit information that they are allowed to. The general rule is to always use the user id in the authentication information and not load it from a view.

Comment: `Again, a lot of 'remembering' for a developer to do`. Programmers are not stupid. They have to learn the correct way to do it, and why. Just saying use a guid because it's more secure doesn't help. And that's why I commented. GUID is no magic bullet and it has implications of using them.

Comment: no, but they make mistakes. We all do, I have many security reviews to show these mistakes are made all the time : )  The framework by default here uses a guid, so the design decision wasn't mine here anyways, but if anything ever goes to the 'end user' it shouldn't be sequential based on security best practices alone. It's trivial to map a guid to an id for FK relationships and index the ID as clustered and the guid as non clustered if you show a performance issue based on usage of the guid Then you get the best of both if the concern (or actual issue) for performance is there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7253/discussion-between-adam-tuliper-and-jgauffin)

Answer (score 0):

No. Nothing magical is going on. You need yourself to assign the correct id to `UserId`.

How could EF or MVC know that you want to use the logged in user's id? Nothing implies that any empty `UserId` property should be the current user's.